# Como instalar modulos do Angular JS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, spring-boot, angular-module

estou criando um aplicação em spring + angular , e por motivos não estou podendo instalar os modulos do angular na pasta do projeto pelo comando bower install... tem como eu instalar esse modulos manualmente e como utiliza-lo?

Comment: Certifique que a pasta dos módulos do Bower está sendo "servida" pelo Spring

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Na página do AngularJS, clique no botão `Download` e depois em `Browse addicional modules`.
Aparecerá uma lista de arquivos do módulos, clique sobre o arquivo do módulo que deseja adicionar, copie o link e adicione das referências.
Vou usar de exemplo o `AngularRoute`, pode ser outro. Pode ser a versão normal para desenvolvimento ou minificada para o modo de produção.

```
<script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.5/angular-route.js" />
```

Deve também adicionar as dependências no módulo principal ou no módulo que for utilizar a dependência como já citado:

```
angular.module('app', ['ngRoute']);
```

Desta forma você não precisará mexer na sua pasta local nem usar o bower. Os arquivos vão ficar armazenados no cache do seu navegador.
Mas se for possível, também pode baixar para sua máquina como já citado acima.

Comment: vlw cara! consegui aqui

Comment: @RobertoOliveira se funcionou para você, marque a resposta do Shura16 como aceita - assim outros usuários interessados no mesmo assunto saberão que sua pergunta recebeu uma solução válida. Abraços!

Answer (score 2):

Você tem que dar o include do `js` do modulo na sua aplicação e depois passa a dependência no seu app, exemplo:

No html:

```
<script src="angular-route.js">
```

No seu modulo principal:

```
angular.module('app', ['ngRoute']);
```

Answer (score 1):

A forma de "instalar um módulo do AngularJS" utilizando Node.js (bower é um middleware Node.js), é utilizando bower install ou npm install.

Porém, como você não está conseguindo dessa forma a outra maneira é fazer isso manualmente, ou seja, baixar o arquivo JS do módulo do Angular e importar o script no teu HTML e no seu Angular app.

Ex:

Baixe o módulo: [angular-filter](https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-filter/0.5.5/angular-filter.js)

Inclua no seu HTML:

```
<script src="angular-filter.js">
```

Depois adicione o módulo no angular:

```
angular.module("app", ["angular.filter"]);
```